# How do I calculate length of streak?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite, window-functions, consecutive-months

I have the following data:

```
date          unit     status
2023-04-30    unit1    1
2023-05-31    unit1    1
2023-08-31    unit1    1
2023-09-30    unit1    1
2023-11-30    unit1    1
2023-12-31    unit1    1
2024-01-31    unit1    1
2024-02-28    unit1    1
```

For a reference date I would like to know the length of the first upcoming "streak" (on MSSQL, used for production, and sqlite, used for unit tests)

### Example 1:

For date **2023-05-15** my desired output is:

```
unit     streak
unit1    3
```

The reason for this is that the first month with status=1 after 2023-05 is 2023-08, and then I just count for each consecutive month.

### Example 2:

For date **2023-11-01** my desired output is:

```
unit     streak
unit1    3
```

The reason is that the first month with status=1 after 2023-11 is 2023-12, and the streak ends on 2024-02 as months with status=0 are not recorded, and the next month with status=1 is more that a month away.

Comment: Using different database engines for production and development is really not the best of ideas.

Comment: In principle I agree. But in this project Python is used as our "center" where data from at bunch of data sources has to be gathered. One could of cause write query code 3-4 different places and validate on the systems, but we chose to write it all one place and validate it all there. This of cause gives the MSSQL vs sqlite problem, but that can for the most part be resolved if we use the generic types in SQLAlchemy, and if we use raw SQL rather than special functionality on MSSQL. Unfortunately any solution to our data challenges will be a compromise :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a `gaps and islands` problem that can be resolved by (value minus row_number), since that is invariant within a consecutive sequence. The start and end dates are just the MIN() and MAX() of the group :

```
WITH cte as (
  SELECT  *, GroupingSet = FORMAT(DATEADD(
                             MONTH, - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY unit ORDER BY [date]), 
                             [date]
                           ), 'yyyy-MM-01')
  FROM    mytable
  WHERE [date] > EOMONTH('2023-05-15') AND [status] = 1
)
SELECT  TOP 1 unit,
        StartDate = MIN([date]),
        EndDate = MAX([date]),
        streak = COUNT(*)
FROM    CTE
GROUP BY unit, GroupingSet
ORDER BY StartDate;
```

NB : The giving date have been converted to the first day of the month so the GroupingSet can be matched withing same year/month !

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/mQogw9e3)

———

Using the row_number method, we can easily obtain the top streak for each unit when considering several units:

```
with cte AS (
  SELECT  *, GroupingSet = FORMAT(DATEADD(
                             MONTH, - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY unit ORDER BY [date]), 
                             [date]
                           ), 'yyyy-MM-01')
  FROM    mytable
  WHERE [date] > EOMONTH('2023-05-15') AND [status] = 1
),
cte2 AS (
  SELECT  unit,
        StartDate = MIN([date]),
        EndDate = MAX([date]),
        streak = COUNT(*)
  FROM    CTE
  GROUP BY unit, GroupingSet
),
cte3 as (
  SELECT *, row_number() over (partition by unit order by streak desc) as rn
  FROM cte2
)
SELECT unit, StartDate, EndDate, streak
FROM cte3
WHERE rn = 1
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/EZ36JWZA)

Comment: I am not sure why everyone is using "month" explicitly, as it does not work across year end. One should probably use YEAR*12 + MONTH - ROW_NUMBER as group id instead.

Comment: I have edited my answer to go across years, can you have la look https://dbfiddle.uk/mQogw9e3

Comment: Thanks, answer has been accepted :) Nice with the demo!

Comment: It seems your "TOP 1" trick does not work if you have multiple units in your dataset! You just take the top row, but not in each group!

Comment: I have updated my answer to take on consideration multiple units, can you have a look

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server and SQLite, calculating the streak requires a combination of common table expressions (CTEs), window functions, and joins. Let's tackle this problem:

**SQL Server Solution**:

```sql
WITH RankedData AS (
    SELECT [date], [unit], [status],
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [unit] ORDER BY [date]) - 
           MONTH([date]) AS GroupingID
    FROM YourTableName
    WHERE [date] > '2023-05-15' AND [status] = 1
)
SELECT TOP 1 [unit], COUNT(*) AS streak
FROM RankedData
GROUP BY [unit], GroupingID
ORDER BY MIN([date]);
```

**SQLite Solution**:
SQLite lacks some of the advanced windowing capabilities of SQL Server, but you can achieve a similar effect with joins and subqueries:

```sql
WITH RankedData AS (
    SELECT [date], [unit], [status],
           strftime('%m', [date]) + 0 - (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [unit] ORDER BY [date])) AS GroupingID
    FROM YourTableName
    WHERE [date] > '2023-05-15' AND [status] = 1
)
SELECT [unit], COUNT(*) AS streak
FROM RankedData
GROUP BY [unit], GroupingID
ORDER BY MIN([date])
LIMIT 1;
```

These scripts should provide the length of the first upcoming streak for the given reference date. Just adjust the date in the WHERE clause as needed.

Comment: Nice! I will test it out tomorrow morning first thing :) And then if it all works as expected, I will accept your answer. I will probably go with the sqlite version as I assume that it will work in both databases.

Comment: Just tested it on the database instead of in SQLAlchemy, and it worked :) Nice nice! Thanks :D

Comment: Most certainly test the speed of each script in their own environments so that you can make a more educated decision. Sometimes just because it works doesn't mean it scales on large tables. I'm sure you were going to anyway. =)

Comment: True, but this is a query that will be run on a few million rows of data, and at the most 5-10 times, so the efficiency is not of the biggest concern :)

Comment: I have tested your solution and got wrong result https://dbfiddle.uk/deidKeye can you have a look

Comment: I just tested it over years, and I agree, I get the wrong result. The "MONTH" part is cheating, as it doesn't work when you go from one year to another.